# practical way to set and sequentially increment a value inside a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var store = map[string]int{}

func breadArrived(num int) {
    if breadTotal, ok := store["bread"]; ok {
        breadTotal += num
    } else {
        store["bread"] = num
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", store)
}

func main() {
    breadArrived(1)
    breadArrived(2)
    breadArrived(3)
}
```

Code above ignores the `+=` operator, so `store["bread"]` always equals to `1`. I assume I'm missing something like "passing by reference" here. Also, is there any more convenient way of doing this?

Comment: `m[k]++` also can increase value of key `k` by 1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're only incrementing the `breadTotal` local variable, and not the value in the `store` map. It should be:

```
store["bread"] = breadTotal + num
```

Also you can simply do:

```
store["bread"] += num
```

Also since indexing a map returns the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the value type for keys which are not yet in the map (zero value for `int` is `0` – properly telling no bread yet), that `if` is completely unnecessary. You can simply do:

```
func breadArrived(num int) {
    store["bread"] += num
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", store)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LQzrbSZudH)):

```
map[bread:1]
map[bread:3]
map[bread:6]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `breadTotal` variable is only a copy of the `map` integer value, you need to reference it as `store["bread"] += num` to increment the `map` integer value.

https://play.golang.org/p/LQzrbSZudH

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var store = map[string]int{}

func breadArrived(num int) {
    store["bread"] += num
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", store)
}

func main() {
    breadArrived(1)
    breadArrived(2)
    breadArrived(3)
}
```

By the way, the first incrementing of the `map` integer works because go initializes everything to a default value, in the case of integers the default value is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple increment like C\C++ style:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var store = map[string]int{}

func main() {
    store["some_key"] = 0
    if _, found:= store["some_key"]; found{
        fmt.Println(store["some_key"])
        store["some_key"]++
        fmt.Println(store["some_key"])
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nyM7GFI1-GW

Comment: A bit of explanation alongside your code would be welcome.